# Custom webpart properties with controls dependent on each other

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation, custom-properties

I have a visual web part with custom properties. I have added 2 fields in the custom properties. One is a check-box and other is a text-box. I have a requirement if check-box is checked then the text-box should be disabled and if the check-box is unchecked then the text-box should be enabled. How can I achieve this? Anyone have any idea please share.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping check box and text box in another user control. Use event handler to achieve your functionality. Hope this helps.

Comment: Try these steps: 1. Create a user control with the two controls
2. Make the web part property non-browable to hide the default editor part controls
3. Use editor part to add the new user control to the web part
4. Use event handler to disable and enable the text box based on the check value